# Pandas DataFrame Apply Efficiency

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe to which I wan't to add a column with a kind of status if there is a matching value in another dataframe. I have the current code which works:

```
df1['NewColumn'] = df1['ComparisonColumn'].apply(lambda x: 'Match' if any(df2.ComparisonColumn == x) else ('' if x is None else 'Missing'))
```

I know the line is ugly, but I get the impression that its inefficient. Can you suggest a better way to make this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`, `isin`, and `isnull`:

Create some dummy data:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ComparisonColumn':np.random.randint(10,20,20)})
df.iloc[4] = np.nan #Create missing data
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ComparisonColumn':np.random.randint(15,30,20)})
```

Do matching with `np.where`:

```
df['NewColumn']  = np.where(df.ComparisonColumn.isin(df2.ComparisonColumn),'Matched',np.where(df.ComparisonColumn.isnull(),'Missing',''))
```

Output:

```
    ComparisonColumn NewColumn
0               12.0          
1               12.0          
2               16.0   Matched
3               11.0          
4                NaN   Missing
5               19.0   Matched
6               16.0   Matched
7               11.0          
8               10.0          
9               11.0          
10              19.0   Matched
11              10.0          
12              10.0          
13              19.0   Matched
14              13.0          
15              14.0          
16              10.0          
17              10.0          
18              14.0          
19              11.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this-I've implemented it and it's a bit faster and it's definitely clearer. Can you comment on why it's faster? Something which maybe  absent from my original post is that the comparisons are text comparisons. Seems funny to use numpy to perform text comparisons.

Comment: @user3535074 Yes,  apply is somewhat of a slow operation in general, I am just using Numpy for if then control and the comparison is taking place with Pandas and isin function.